# Is it possible to Flash Two devices using 2 JTAG connected to single PC?

Tags: usb, xilinx, jtag

I need to flash two devices using Xilinx impact command line. Both devices are equipped with JTAG and connected to different USB port of PC.

My flash script contains following code:

```
setmode -bscan 
setcable -p auto
identify
assignfile -p 1 -file \test_AP_Ch1.bit`   
program -p 1
quit
```

Is there any command through which I could specify the COM port to run this batch file.

Comment: We need to know the board and/or programmer name. The line `setcable -p auto` specifies the selected programer 'cable'. E.g. a Xilinx FTDI based usb programer is names `USB21`, `USB22`, ... I haven't found out in which order the devices are enumerated. The best solution is to use Digilent Programers, if possible. They have an unique ID.

Comment: I am using _JTAG-HS2™ Programming Cable for Xilinx.

Comment: [This one from Digilent?](https://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=JTAG-HS2) If so, it can be accessed and uniquely addressed by IDs. I can search my code for the proper iMPACT lines.

Comment: Yes, I am using same cable for flashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `setcable -p auto` specifies the selected programmer 'cable'.
Digilent programmers can be addressed by IDs.

```
setmode -bs
setCable -port auto
setCable -target "digilent_plugin DEVICE=SN:210203356213 FREQUENCY=10000000"
identify
assignfile -p 1 -file myBitfile.bit
program -p 1
quit
```

You can see the serials when you connect one cable by another and look for new serials in iMAPCT (setup cable dialog box).

Comment: Thanks a ton. Really grateful. U saved my day